# Sync OneDrive for Business in Win10 on VirtualBox with shared folder on host system

Tags: virtualbox, sync, onedrive, network-drive

I have a **Debian linux** system and would like to sync my **OneDrive for Business** folders. There are some linux clients for OneDrive, that do not really work, they either don't work with OneDrive for Business or with folders shared with me by others.

I've tried the following. I set up **VirtualBox** with a **Windows 10 Pro guest** on the debian host. I've installed OneDrive for Business in the guest. I created a shared folder on the Debian host that is mounted as a network drive with a windows drive letter in Win10.

*However OneDrive does not allow the folder to be on a network drive.*

Is there a workaround? I do not want to save the files within the host as I don't want the VirtualBox .vdi-file to become too large.

Comment: Possible ways: SSH, SFTP, directory symbolic link.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, could you please elaborate? I don't understand, how ssh or a symlink would help ...

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. I don't know if it's because it's network drive or the fact that a shared folder is not NTFS, though.

Comment: @Marcel, I assume Microsoft wants to exclude this use case. There may not be a technical reason.

Comment: @AmelseEtomer Oh yeah. It's 100% possible. Microsoft either just didn't think of it or don't want to do it.

Comment: There is `ondrive` package in Debian starting with bullseye. I can confirm that the current version (2.4.4-1) syncs the shared folders if I add them to `~/.config/onedrive/business_shared_folders` configuration file. But that is not what you are asking about, right?